# where can I find sys/conf.h in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, unix

when I am testing some code about STREAMS, `#include <sys/conf.h>` need to be  added to the program, but `sys/conf.h` seems to not exist in Ubuntu. where can I find it ?

Comment: Isn't STREAMS a SysV-specific framework? I see that `sys/conf.h` is present on a Solaris host but I am not surprised at all to not find it on Linux.

Comment: if the code you are testing is a package, and it has a makefile, see if it has a configure.in file. If so then run `configure`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exist in most linux system. POSIX do not require OS implement it. I find this problem when i am reading APUE(by Stevens),but the program could run even you delete this include sentence.